# Windows 10 Alarm is running but doesn't exist in my programs or features

Tags: windows, alarm

I'm talking about Windows built-in alarm. I've set it up way before. It still runs every day at 4:00 I get the notification in the lower right popup. However, to start the app and update alarm or set a new one, I just can't do it. I can't find that app anywhere. (Google says look for the app "Alarms and Clock"). Look at my start panel - searching for term "clock" produces the same result:

[image]

P.S. I tried Start -> run -> entering "alarm" or "alarms", I got red X "Windows can't find..."

Answer (score 1):

You've probably set the alarm in the Clock app, rather than the alarm app.

[image]

Start > search for 'Clock' and load it up. Then delete/disable/edit the existing alarm(s).

[image]

Comment: Nope. Clock doesn't exist either (look at my original post, I wrote I tried with clock also)

Comment: This was partly-solved. See the full solution in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the previous answer was semi-successful.
True, I didn't have app "Alarms & Clocks", how Google suggested and some of my friends and coleagues. Spikey_richie suggested to look for app "Clock" which I couldn't find therefore I assumed I don't have it installed.

However, the solution was this: I have some strange mixture of English and Croatian (my local) language on my Windows, and although everything is in English, all the built-in-apps are in Croatian (strangely), so I couldn't find "Clock". Therefore I found "Sat" (Croatian localization), thanks to my colleague Davor Smonkar.

Anyone who might have similar problem, look for the localization of your local language of your built-in-apps in Windows.

Comment: Sneaky! Glad you got it sorted.